# spark cassandra application fails with RECEIVED SIGNAL 15: SIGTERM

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm running a spark application using spark-cassandra-connector.

The following are my spark-submit options

> --class com.mobi.vserv.driver.Query5kPids1
>   --num-executors 4
>   --executor-memory 4g
>   --executor-cores 2
>   --driver-memory 4g

But I keep getting the following error

> 16/03/30 11:57:07 ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver
>   10.225.46.84:60637 disassociated! Shutting down.

Also the cassandra gets connected and then gets disconnecd

```
INFO Cluster: New Cassandra host /10.229.84.123:9042 added

INFO LocalNodeFirstLoadBalancingPolicy: Added host 10.229.84.123 (us-east)

INFO Cluster: New Cassandra host /10.229.19.210:9042 added -> This is Seed Node
(This Message -> INFO LocalNodeFirstLoadBalancingPolicy: Doesnt show for Seed Node)

INFO Cluster: New Cassandra host /10.95.215.249:9042 added

INFO LocalNodeFirstLoadBalancingPolicy: Added host 10.95.215.249 (us-east)

INFO Cluster: New Cassandra host /10.43.182.167:9042 added

INFO LocalNodeFirstLoadBalancingPolicy: Added host 10.43.182.167 (us-east)

INFO Cluster: New Cassandra host /10.155.34.67:9042 added

INFO LocalNodeFirstLoadBalancingPolicy: Added host 10.155.34.67 (us-east)

INFO Cluster: New Cassandra host /10.237.235.209:9042 added

INFO LocalNodeFirstLoadBalancingPolicy: Added host 10.237.235.209 (us-east)

INFO CassandraConnector: Connected to Cassandra cluster: dmp Cluster

INFO CassandraConnector: Disconnected from Cassandra cluster: dmp Cluster
```

And finally Yarn Kills the application master

> ERROR ApplicationMaster: RECEIVED SIGNAL 15: SIGTERM

I also added

> --conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=1024
>    --conf  spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead=1024

But then the application keeps running forever.

I dont know what seems to be the problem here as have ran the application before and it ran successfully

POM used is

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0-M1</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
   <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.6</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
   <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10</artifactId>
   <version>1.4.0-M1</version>
  </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution as there was a bug with spark-cassandra-connector 1.4.0-M1 as mentioned here https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/SPARKC-214

So when I used the next release ie 1.4.0-M2. It worked fine.

But still whats seem to be most weird is this has earlier worked with 1.4.0-M1.